# Is there a Chromium flag to automate the selection of Share Audio when selecting Desktop Capture Source?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer

When using puppeteer, is there an argument that can be passed to the array of default args to automate the selection of the `Share Audio` checkbox that becomes visible when selecting a capture source (shown in image below) ? If not, is there any way to capture the browser's audio when using `getDisplayMedia`, aside from recording the mic output from `getUserMedia`?

[image: Chrome Capture Source Dialog]

Comment: I'm sorry but i think there isn't available yet.
There is a YouTube video which talk about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRG7DtTvGfw